# ¿Cómo encontrar el valor de un hash?

Tags: javascript

Hay un metodo `hash` al cúal le paso un texto y este me devuleve un entero.

Mi intención es crear una función que genere varias combinaciones hasta que coincida con el hash correspondiente que es `83503320370387`.

Sé que para conseguir ese número aproximado hay que colocar 10 letras y el diccionario que se usa es el siguiente `abehimoprstuv`

```js
function encontrarHash() {
    let resultado;
    const diccionario = "abehimoprstuv";
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let letra = hash(diccionario[i]);
        resultado = letra;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

**Actualización**

Metodo Hash

```js
function hash(x) {
    seed = 41;
    diccionario = "abehimoprstuv";
    for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    seed = (seed * 17 + diccionario.indexOf(x[i]));
    }
    return seed;
}
```

Necesito ayuda para aclarar mejor esta idea. ¿Cómo genero estas combinaciones de manera automatizada para dar con el entero correspondiente?

Comment: 10 letras permutadas, no veo que estés permutando las letras. Eso da `10!` que son `3.628.800` combinaciones posibles. Eso asumiendo que con esas 10 letras se consigue el valor que buscas y que la función `hash` realmente genere valores únicos con una probabilidad de colisión muy baja.

Comment: @MauricioContreras No entiendo mucho lo que dices, pero ahora estoy usando el CharAt, mi problema aquí es centra mejor la idea, con CharAt y un par de for logré generar una secuencia de cambinaciones, pero lineales y no está límitado a 10 digitos, no estoy seguro si un método burbuja sería una posible solución, pero seguiría teniendo el problema de no tener el límite de 10 digitos.

Comment: El texto original tiene 10 letras o simplemente se trata de un texto de cualquier longitud formado por las letras del diccionario? Aclara mejor el problema porque no se entiende muy bien. Por otro lado, lo que intentas hacer se llama *fuerza bruta* y es bastante costoso en tiempo y recursos. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras El metodo hash recibe un argumento x, el reto es encontrar este argumento x que es una palabra de 10 letras que se compone únicamente de los siguientes caracteres: abehimoprstuv (con capacidad de repetir u omitir uno o varios de ellos). Esta palabra se supone que al aplicarle el hash da el resultado de 83503320370387. Si, es cierto que mi forma en este momento es fuerza bruta, pero por que no sé si existe otra mejor forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/zbh530sa/

La palabra es : perserverar

Puedes hacer esto:

```js
function dehash(x) {
  diccionario = 'abehinoprstuv';
  seed = 83503320370387;
  str = '';
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    realNumber = seed % 17;
    seed = (seed - realNumber) / 17;
    str += diccionario[realNumber];
  }
  return str;
}

console.log(dehash().split('').reverse().join(''));
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Debes escribir la respuesta en español. Puedes hacer click en [edit]